# What do the square brackets do in pdo execute statments?

Tags: php, pdo, brackets

I have always used square brackets inside the parenthesis my pdo execute statements

```
$query->execute([$variable]);
```

While working with checkboxes for the first time recently, I discovered that I had to remove the square brackets

```
$query->execute($variable);
```

otherwise i got the error

> Array to String conversion

So what are the purpose of the square brackets and are they necessary?

Comment: It's the [short syntax for an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

The argument passed to `execute` must be an array.

`[...]` creates an array in PHP.

If that errors with *Array to String conversion* then `$variable` must **already** be an array.